# Django hosting on Cloudera applications: server not starting

Tags: python, django, cloudera

I am trying to port a `django` web application from some server to `cloudera` "`applications`" (data science workbench) and I was trying to make it work. I managed to do so with `flask` and `fastapi` applications, just the `django` framework is missing. My problem, when trying the base setup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/), locally works like a charm but when I try to start up the server from an instance in `cloudera`, the server does not start and, more curiosuly, I get a weird output related to some package of the image I am spinning. (you can see I am bypassing the traditional runserver command on `django` because in the `cloudera applications` side I cannot run shells directly and also due to the fact that I would to tie it up with some environmental variable)

below the `manage.py`

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    port_to_pass = 8000
    args = ['name', 'runserver', '127.0.0.1:%d' % port_to_pass]
    execute_from_command_line(args)
```

weird "`print`" (the instance I am spinning has got the exact same package versions installed locally):
[image]

when I should be getting:

[image]

any idea what might the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra entry.py script:

```py
!pip install django

!python manage.py runserver 8000
```

Comment: thing is django is installed and  this line (from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line) is run proeprly, it would not be possible to do it otherwise

Comment: I had the exactly same issue with your code.
Then tried with setting default port runserver.default_port, set os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true" and additional called django.core.management.call_command('runserver'). Got the same issue again. But with !python manage.py runserver 8000 it works properly and the Website is available